# Restricted LDAP mimic server backed on SQL

Tags: ldap, postgresql, sql

I may not be an expert on the subject, but it seems to me that 99% of any LDAP server installation is used only to provide user authentication credentials and nothing more.

Given this restricted scope use, and being that exactly what I need, I would like to know if there are any simple SQL<->LDAP mapper implementing only `posixAccount` objectclass, because it seems too cubersome to me to have another database to manage (like OpenLDAP) just for this, and I would like to use my already running PostgreSQL to provide the LDAP interface many software already supports.

Comment: OpenLDAP does support `backend sql` but it is full fledged, not a simple mapper. If you really don't want to manage two user stores, I'd guess that making PostgreSQL use LDAP for authentication will be easier. You also have to remember that lots of software do use group membership to decide whatever to authenticate user or not...